# JVM in iOS app to run Android apps?

Tags: java, android, iphone, ios, jvm

If one were to implement a JVM into an iOS app, couldn't it run Android apps *inside* of iOS?

If so, how would he go about doing so?

Answer (score 0):

He (or she) would need to

- Implement a JVM that can run Dalvik Executable (DEX) files
- Build an emulation layer that

  - Translates Android UI layouts into roughly equivalent iOS layouts (or interprets the layouts and renders them directly)
  - Maps calls to Android's system APIs and UI toolkit functions into their iOS equivalents
  - Interprets iOS events (touch interactions, notifications, lifecycle, etc) and maps them to reasonable Android equivalents
- ...

It's worth noting that the folks at Blackberry have built a mechanism for running *some* Android apps within the Blackberry OS. However, it has been a major effort and is limited to relatively simple apps that do not use native code, complex layouts, private APIs, etc. While technically feasible, this type of emulation is difficult to do well.